# insert into command in vb that has ERROR13 Type Mismatch (Connecting to an .mdb database)

Tags: database, vb.net

I was wondering what's wrong with my code when I run the program, there is no error in the code but something is wrong with the type of variables is accepting, maybe? My database has 3 colums, the first column is the primary key, being auto incremented, I dont need to input anything but when I was inserting into the 2 columns, I got the TYPE MISMATCH ERROR in vb...

PS: I'm in database programming...

Here let me show you my code:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Set rsAdd = New ADODB.Recordset
s = "insert into SongReq(SongTitle,Singer) values('" & Text1.Text & "', '" & Text2.Text & "')"
rsAdd.Open s, connect, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
MsgBox "Song Added, Thank you for sending your request!"
Text1.Text = ""
Text2.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: What is data type of column SongTitle and Singer?

Comment: its Text type.. I'm using MSAccess .mdb database... How can there be a TYPE MISMATCH?

Comment: At row rsAdd.Open s, connect, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic. Does it actually like that or you missing copy the "()"?

Comment: I had the same code with a different exercise and it actually worked, and this time, it doesnt.. I was wondering what could the problem be.. :(

Comment: how about showing your full code